# Custom calendar view with dates highlights and events marked

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar, android-calendar

I'm developing an app with a custom calendar view in which I need to highlight some dates with a specific colour.Also I need to show particular events which is obtained from JSON response from server as and wen a date is selected.I created a calendar with CalendarView and succeeded in selecting the dates.Can I create a custom calendar for the same purpose in any other methods?And I need the calendar to be scrollable,and fetches data from the server as and when a month is selected in the scroll.Please help with sample projects if possible.

Comment: please check it the following link:https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Comment: @RajanBhavsar But I need a monthly calendar only...and I need to display the events only when I select a date...and that too the data fetched from a server...

Comment: Please check it out the Source as there is having an oiption to display with month View